# Using OR with AND conditions Simultaneously into AdoTable Filter in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am tryin to apply following filter on a AdoTable component but it shows error:

```
((details_id = 15) OR (details_id = 16) OR (details_id = 17)) AND(personel_id = 5)
```

the error is :

```
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

whats the wrong and how can I do this filter.
I previously searched it on Delphi help but could not to solve it.
Special Thanks in advance.

Comment: No its a sample code. I tried your comment but not solved the problem.

Comment: What makes you think the error has anything to do with `OR` and `AND`?

Comment: I test the property with : (details_id = 15) OR (details_id = 16) OR (details_id = 17) and it was OK but when + 'AND' condition Not ok

Comment: Please show the source code where you assign this boolean expression. The problem seems not to be the expression but the way you use it: you assign it (or use it as argument) to something which do not accept a boolean.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea if it's relevant, but you squeeze the "AND" and the "(" together, whereas for the "OR"s there's a space. Just a wild guess (don't think it's this, but it was all that sprang to mind when I saw it): Try `((details_id = 15) OR (details_id = 16) OR (details_id = 17)) AND (personel_id = 5)` instead.

Comment: Otherwise, you could try `(details_id >= 15) AND (details_id <= 17) AND (personel_id = 5)` to eliminate the "OR"s (again - just a wild guess)

Comment: Did you try a simple condition involving only `personel_id`?

Comment: Using simple personel_id=5 Is ok

Comment: adding spaces does not solved the problem. also the I dont need a range of numbers(the above code is a sample code) because the numbers are not in sequence

Comment: I suggest you use a `TADOQuery` instead of a `TADOTable`.

Comment: Another possibility is (personal_id = 5) and (details_id between 15 and 17). Why are you using a string expression and not parameters in your SQL query ... because it's not a query.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make a filter on a table it is much more convenient to use `TADOQuery` and put:

```
TADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ((details_id = 15) OR (details_id = 16) OR (details_id = 17)) AND (personel_id = 5)'
```

where `TableName` is the name of your actual table. It is also much easier to manipulate with parameter values this way.

Even better you can write this:

```
TADOQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ((details_id IN (15, 16, 17)) AND (personel_id = 5)'
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew this method myself before, but I wanted to know the way of filtering TAdoTable. I'm sure there is a way to do that!  Although I solved it this way.